# C# How to use MemoryStream with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, memorystream

My current code is:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            stream.Close();
            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }


        return byteArray;
}
```

Is there any way to make this work with multithreading, or use every core of my CPU
to make it faster?

Comment: Trying to save a single stream with multithreading is asking for trouble, I also doubt this is a bottleneck

Answer (score 5):

If you are converting multiple images to byte array and you know them upfront, then you can use the Parallel.ForEach loop and have this done there so that they can be done in different cores if available. But i do no think modifying this single method to use multiple cores is worth the effort and saves any time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do it multithreaded. Doing so might damage the stream.
The image must be saved to the stream at an offset of zero. If any additional data has been written to the stream before saving the image, the image data in the stream will be corrupted.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't know how to make it use multiple cores, but to make it threadsafe you need to do the following.  First declare a private static Object

```
private static readonly Object _obj = new Object();
```

Then modify your code as below:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    lock(_obj)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            stream.Close();
            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless your using a Mac I doubt the time it would take to save an image would warrant this

Comment: Static methods inside a multi-thread should always be synchronized.  In addition there is a common mis-perception on the cost of locking an object.  It isn't that significant and and well worth protection from corruption

Comment: @edepperson "Static methods inside a multi-thread should always be synchronized" is not true.

Comment: Public static methods should almost always be thread-safe. If they work with shared data structures then that means they *should* use some kind of synchronization. So in that respect @edepperson is right. Most of the static methods in the BCL are labeled this way. With that said, the use of a lock here is pointless. The method is already thread-safe because it is working with a new `MemoryStream` and `byte[]`. There is no shared data structure in play other than `Image` which is passed as a parameter. So the onus is on the caller to ensure `Image` is not access from multiple threads.

Comment: I down-voted this because it's completely wrong. As Brian Gideon points out, the method as written by the OP is inherently thread-safe because it uses no outside data other than the image, and it's up to the caller to make sure that the image is protected from concurrent changes.